# add strong element in ItemDataBound around span

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way in the code-behind to add a strong element around my `asp:Label` in the ItemDataBound event (between the `li` and `asp:Label` elements) when rendered?

**the markup**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**csharp code behind**, this is where I was hoping there is a way to add the strong element.

```
void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Label test = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");

    }
}
```

[image]

I know there are easier ways to do this but I need to do it this way specifically unfortunately.

Comment: Use a `Literal`(with `Mode="PassThrough"`) control instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty hacky and doesn't actually give you a `strong` control to work with, but I suppose something like this might work:

```
void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Label test = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");

        Literal literal1 = new Literal();
        literal1.Text = "<strong>";

        e.Item.Controls.AddAt(e.Item.Controls.IndexOf(test), literal1);

        Literal literal2 = new Literal();
        literal2.Text = "</strong>";

        e.Item.Controls.AddAt(e.Item.Controls.IndexOf(test) + 1, literal2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easily.  So far as I know, there is no `<asp:Strong>` tag.  The easiest thing to do here would be to just put the  tag in your code.

However, if you need to optionally implement the strong tag, the same thing can be accomplished by setting the css on your label to `font-weight: bold` (which is the same as wrapping content in the strong tag), or declaratively by setting the CssClass attribute of the label, ie

`Label1.CssClass = "myStrongCssClass";`

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind you will need to find the label within the template then 
    Label1.Font.Bold = true;